# Structured streaming creating no files other than spark-metadata (Parquet)

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run a structured streaming application which writes the output files as parquet to Google cloud storage. I don't see any errors. But it does not write the files to GCS location. I could see only spark-metadata folder. Any idea how I can debug?

```
WindowDuration = "60 minutes";
SlideDuration = "10 minutes";
Data_2 = complete_data;
Data_2 = data_2.withColumn("creationDt", functions.to_timestamp( functions.from_unixtime(col(topics+"."+event_timestamp).divide(1000.0))));
Data_2 = data_2
        .withWatermark("creationDt","1 minute")
        .groupBy(col(topics+"."+keyField),functions.window(col("creationDt"), windowDuration, slideDuration),col(topics+"."+aggregateByField))
        .count();

Query_2 = data_2
        .withColumn("startwindow", col("window.start"))
        .withColumn("endwindow", col("window.end"))
        .withColumn("endwindow_date", col("window.end").cast(DataTypes.DateType))
        .writeStream()
        .format("parquet")
        .partitionBy("endwindow_date")
        .option("path",dataFile_2)
        .option("truncate", "false")
        .outputMode("append")
                .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointFile_2).start();

Query_2.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: What's the Spark version? What's in web UI's SQL tab? What's under `spark-metadata` folder? What's the source(s)? Any aggregations? More, more, more...

Comment: I am using Spark version 2.2 provided by Google dataproc. Spark metadata folder contains many files named with numbers like 220,221 etc. All these files have "v1" as content. I don't see any valuable contents.

Comment: What about web UI? Anything? The invaluable contents is very valuable as it shows that the query's running.

Comment: I am just changing the firewall so that I can access UI. I will update in sometime. Your help is much appreciated. I have really tried a lot and I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: UI shows like "all the tasks succeeded overtime a batch runs. I have three streaming queries in the same program. Will that be a problem? Updated the question with code also. I have three similar queries with 30 min window, 60 min window and 24 hours window.

Comment: I do see this exception as WARN. 17/09/20 16:49:48 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer: Caught exception
java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
 at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.closeResponder(DataStreamer.java:927)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.endBlock(DataStreamer.java:578)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:755)

Comment: 17/09/20 16:33:21 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.6.1-hadoop2
17/09/20 16:34:25 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer: Caught exception
java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
 at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.closeResponder(DataStreamer.java:927)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.endBlock(DataStreamer.java:578)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:755)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  I see this WARN too. 17/09/20 16:35:24 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
 at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:478)
 at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:63)

Comment: If @tix is right that append on GCS is the issue, consider putting the data in Cloud SQL (or some other structured database) and use "update" mode. Structured Streaming doesn't natively support jdbc output yet, but this Databricks post shows how to do it (scroll down to "Databases"): https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html.

Alternatively, you can use "complete" mode on GCS (write the entire table every window period), or use "append" on the on-cluster HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with `.outputMode("append")` line. GCS is not a file system and does not support append mode.

I am guessing that this line blows up and the exception is just gobbled up somewhere:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/fs/gcs/GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java#L1175

Comment: It's the only acceptable way for the writeStream. If you put "update" or "complete" it gives you an error